# How to specify a format of a parameter in URL in Elixir Phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I specify the format of a certain parameters in a URL? For example, for this URL: `my_website.com/users/123` I want the `user_id` parameter in the URL to be integer and positive.

How can I do that? Is it done via `web/routes.ex` via regular expressions?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible in the Router in Phoenix because of the way the Router is implemented -- it can only match a path segment (text between `/`) with an exact constant string, a string with a constant prefix, or any string. You can check it manually in the controller action like this:

```
def show(conn, %{"user_id" => user_id}) do
  case Integer.parse(user_id) do
    {user_id, ""} when user_id > 0 ->
      # user_id is valid positive integer
      text(conn, "ok")
    _ ->
      # user_id was either not an integer or a negative integer
      text(conn, "not ok")
  end
end
```

Comment: “The best you can do is to handle this in your `Controller`'s”—this is sorta wrong advice. `Plug`s were invented for that.

Comment: @mudasobwa you're right. I've toned down the language.

Comment: what if "user_id" was an integer? the thing is, we don't know if it's integer or string or "fdsfdsfdsfd". Integer.parse accepts only strings.

Comment: @Kurama will you be calling this function directly with "user_id" containing an integer value? All params will be passed by Phoenix as strings (unless you have a Plug modifying the original values).

Answer (score 3):

This is usually being done with [`Plug`](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/understanding-plug#section-module-plugs)s. According to the documentation:

> Module plugs are another type of `Plug` that let us define a connection transformation in a module. The module only needs to implement two functions:
>
> - `init/1` which initializes any arguments or options to be passed to call/2
> - `call/2` which carries out the connection transformation. call/2 is just a function plug that we saw earlier

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Plugs.Checker do
  import Plug.Conn

  @validator ~r|\A\d+\z|

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(%Plug.Conn{params: %{"user_id" => user_id}} = conn, _default) do
    # ⇓ HERE
    unless Regex.match(@validator, user_id), do: raise
    assign(conn, :user_id, user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that this will not fall back to matching the rest of the routes like someone who wants regex matching in routes would expect to happen in case of a non-match (same as my answer but it might be less obvious for someone new to Phoenix). I believe `raise` will also cause a 5xx response by default.

Comment: **NB** the @Dogbert’s comment above has an added value, please read. Also, be aware that I used `raise` there just as a pseudocode stub/example.

Comment: how do I specify what controller and action should `HelloPhoenix.Plugs.Checker` be applied to?

Comment: In the respective `pipeline`. Check `Plug` documentation I have linked.

Comment: what about if I wanted to apply it only to a single action?

Comment: AFAIU, this single action should go through it’s dedicated pipeline.

Comment: You can add a plug to a single action by adding `plug HelloPhoenix.Plugs.Checker when action in [:index]` to your controller. See the "Guards" section in https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.Pipeline.html.